# Термін pansharpening українською

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

В обробці зображень є такий процес злиття панхроматичного зображення високої роздільної здатності з багатоканальним зображенння нижчої роздільної здатності для отримання єдиного кольорового зображення високої роздільної здатності.

Comment: Раджу зайти на slovotvir.org.ua й додати це слово, а там його перекладуть.